# python regex suffix matching

Tags: python, regex

for a typical set of word suffixes (ize,fy,ly,able...etc), I want to know if a given words ends with any of them, and subsequently remove them. I know this can be done iteratively with word.endswith('ize') for example, but I believe there is a neater regex way of doing it.. tried positive lookahead with an ending marker $ but for some reason didn't work:

```
pat='(?=ate|ize|ify|able)$'
word='terrorize'
re.findall(pat,word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually (?:)
Check this out:

```
re.sub(r"(?:ate|ize|ify|able)$", "", "terrorize")
```

Have a look at this site [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).
There are tones of useful regex skills. Hope you enjoy it.

BTW, the python library itself is a neat & wonderful tutorial.
I do help() a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Little-known fact: `endswith` accepts a tuple of possibilities:

```
if word.endswith(('ate','ize','ify','able')):
    #...
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't indicate which string was found, so it doesn't help with removing the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

A lookahead is an anchor pattern, just like `^` and `$` anchor matches to a specific location but are not themselves a match.

You *want* to match these suffixes, but at the end of a word, so use the word-edge anchor `\b` instead:

```
r'(ate|ize|ify|able)\b'
```

then use `re.sub()` to replace those:

```
re.sub(r'(ate|ize|ify|able)\b', '', word)
```

which works just fine:

```
>>> word='terrorize'
>>> re.sub(r'(ate|ize|ify|able)\b', '', word)
'terror'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need adjust parenthese, just change `pat` from:

```
(?=ate|ize|ify|able)$
```

to:

```
(?=(ate|ize|ify|able)$)
```

If you need remove the suffixes later, you could use the pattern:

```
^(.*)(?=(ate|ize|ify|able)$)
```

Test in REPL:

```
>>> pat = '^(.*)(?=(ate|ize|ify|able)$)'
>>> word = 'terrorize'
>>> re.findall(pat, word)
[('terror', 'ize')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's word-by-word matching then simply remove the look-ahead check, the **$** caret is sufficient.